# Convert Array of Arrays into array of objects

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object

I have an `Angular` app where I have an `array` of arrays like below.

```
array1 = [{'1', 'Tom'},{'2','Rob'}].
```

I need to convert this to:

```
array2 = [{'id':'1','name':'Tom', 'city':'ny'}, 
          {'id':'2','name':'Rob', 'city':'dc'}]

export class TempObject {
  constructor(public id: string, 
              public name: string, 
              public city: string) {
  }
}
```

Please see that object class has another property city that is not part of `array1`.
Should we only loop the `array1` and create an instance of  `TempObject` or is there any simplest way?

Comment: `{'1', 'Tom'}` isn't valid JS

Comment: Maybe you did a mistake  by writing `array1` however you can do this by using a `.map`

Answer (score 0):

I have adjusted your starting point to be an array of arrays as your question suggests this is what you have to start with. Bear in mind the `city` isn't in that array of arrays, so you'll have to decide how to handle that.

```
const array1 = [['1', 'Tom'], ['2', 'Rob']];

class TempObject {
  constructor(public id: string, 
              public name: string, 
              public city: string = '') {
  }
}

const array2 = array1.map((val, idx) => new TempObject(val[0], val[1]));

console.log(JSON.stringify(array2));
```